# In Hyperledger Composer, is it possible to have a set of participants that can be used in multiple business networks?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I currently have two business networks modeled in my Composer. The idea is that one network stores reference data (**NetworkA**) and the other stores processed transactions (**NetworkB**).

**NetworkB** needs to query the data in **NetworkA** in order to process the transactions properly. This means that the users in **NetworkB** needs to have **NetworkA** ACLs as well.

Is it possible to define participants once in Composer? Or are you forced to duplicate your particpants in both business networks?

Answer (score 1):

No - the participants are unique to the Business Network.

Using standard composer functions, the 2 networks are separate and do not communicate.  You could use the getNativeApi() function to use Native Fabric calls to connect to the second network.

[This tutorial illustrates](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/invoke-composer-network) how you might achieve what you are are suggesting.  However, you should be aware that using this method will bypass the Composer ACLs when accessing the 2nd Network.  getNativeApi() is described in [this Composer document](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts).